# Api Gateway Authorizer keeps returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless

I have setup an Api Gateway endpoint `/auth/login` with proxies to the following Python Lambda function:

```
        response = client.admin_initiate_auth(
            UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID,
            ClientId=CLIENT_ID,
            AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': email,
                'PASSWORD': password,
            },
            ClientMetadata={
                'username': email,
                'password': password,
            }
        )
```

I can successfully login with my username/password credentials and receiving the following response:

```
{
    "id_token": "eyJraWQiOiJ...",
    "refresh_token": "eyJjdHkiOiJ...",
    "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiJ...",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Now I try to access an private Api Gateway endpoint which uses an Authorizer through Postman or curl and sending the **access_token**:

[image: Api Gateway Authorizer]

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://my_api.endpoint.com/user/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: eyJraWQiOiJ...' \
--data-raw '{
    "email": "my_test_email@stackoverflow.com"
}'
```

But I keep receiving:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I have tried to send the *id_token* instead but with the same result. What am I missing?